# Python: How do I utilize the .json function over a list of get requests?

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am using the Distance Matrix API to get the time it would take to travel between two points but I'm having an issue calling the .json function on my list of get requests.

```
#creates url for API call to get travel time between two cities (my list includes 7 origin and destination pairs)
full_url = [f'{url}+"origins="+{item}+"&destinations="+{row}+"&key="+{apikey}' for item, row in zip(origin, destination)]

#get request to API
r = [requests.get(url) for url in full_url]

#calls .json on each get request in r
time = []
for response in r:
    time.append(response.json()['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['text'])
```

When I call .json i get the error:

**AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'json'**

How do I use a for loop to call .json on each element of r?

Comment: Which version of the requests module are you using?

Comment: I'm using Version 2.22.0 of the requests module

Comment: What is curious is that is looks like your requests.get is returning a `bytes` instead of a `Response` object. Can you please extend your example?

Answer (score 0):

`json.loads()` will solve your problem.

I created a dummy routine with 3 test URLs to demonstrate.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests, json

API_key = 'xxxxx___yourkeyhere'

urls = [
    'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=Washington,DC&destinations=New+York+City,NY&key=' + API_key,
    'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=Houston,TX&destinations=New+York+City,NY&key=' + API_key,
    'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=Reno,NV&destinations=New+York+City,NY&key=' + API_key,
]

time = []
for url in urls: 
    r = requests.get(url)
    if r.status_code==200:
        data = json.loads(r.text)
        time.append(data['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['text'])
print(time)

['3 hours 44 mins', '23 hours 58 mins', '1 day 15 hours']
```